# Converting between WikidPad, reStructuredText and HTML

Tags: python, html, wiki, converters, restructuredtext

I've got plenty of information stored in [WikidPad](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/) notebook format and now I need a way to convert it to [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) (for another wiki).
At the same time I need a possibility of publishing this info on the web (but, as I now see, I can get it using WikidPad's "Export to HTML" option).
So, the main question is how to convert between WikidPad and reStructuredText and vice versa (automatically and fast)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) program will convert between a variety of markup formats, including reStructuredText and HTML.  I don't know if it natively supports WikiPad, but you can certainly use HTML as your intermediate representation.

That is, you can translate WikiPad to HTML, and then HTML to reStructuredText.

Comment: Thank you! "WikidPad <-> HTML <-> reStructuredText" is a great idea. I'll try it with this "pandoc" program you recommended.

Comment: I tried this out and, unfortunately, it didn't work for me. 1) "pandoc" lead to problems with encoding (UTF-8) - so I just used [rst2html.py](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/tools.html#rst2html-py) from docutils.  2) It turns out, WikidPad still does not support HTML import (it imports from .mpt only).

Comment: Do you have a link that describes the input file format for WikiPad?

Comment: As I understand, it has its own format: [WikidPadSyntax](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/help/SyntaxEscape.html). And it allows to import from [Multipage Text Format](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/help/MultipageTextFormat.html) only.